# Loop through similar file extension but different prefix name: Bash script

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I have 15 pair of array files for which I need to perform certain operation (say subtraction).
My file names are:

> pr1_A.txt
>   evs1_A.txt
>   pr2_A.txt
>   evs2_A.txt
>   ...
>   pr15_A.txt
>   evs15_A.txt

I want to perform:

> pr1_A - evs1_A
>   pr2_A - evs2_A
>   ...
>   pr15_A - evs15_A

Can anybody guide me how to do it using a `for` loop.

Comment: @genisage undelete your answer please, we'll fix it. I think the problem was in the question more tha in your answer.

Comment: please add to your question the information you had provided to genisage

Comment: In my case, r is variable in the file name, x1 = evs_Amon_r1i1p1.txt, y1 = pr_Amon_r1i1p1.txt, x2 = evs_Amon_r2i1p1.txt, y2 = pr_Amon_r2i1p1.txt, x3=evs_Amon_r1i1p2.txt, y3 = pr_Amon_r1i1p2.txt ....etc. Variable is r part of the file name in the middle, which is common for both evs and pr files.

Comment: ok @user962808. genisage's answer may help you. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
for n in evs_Amon*
do
  tmp=${n:3}
  x='pr'$tmp
  y='evs'$tmp
  #do stuff using x and y
done
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for this my n is string actually it is x = pr_Amon_CCSM4_r1i1p1.txt; y = evs_Amon_CCSM4_r1i1p1.txt, then for n =2,  x = pr_Amon_CCSM4_r1i1p2.txt; y = evs_Amon_CCSM4_r1i1p2.txt ... for n = 10 x = pr_Amon_CCSM4_r2i1p1.txt; y = evs_Amon_CCSM4_r2i1p1.txt whereas for n = 12, x = pr_Amon_CCSM4_r1i1p6.txt; y = evs_Amon_CCSM4_r1i1p6.txt. How to declair string n in this case ?

Comment: Excelent! +1 for that